# rigging problem connecting two bones at the tail

Tags: rigging, bones

how can I connect [image]the tail of a bone to another tail of a bone?

Answer (score 0):

This may sound like a bit of a cop-out, but you don't have to.

If you want those heads to stay in the same position, use a **Copy Location Constraint**, instead.